# Manage multiple uploading files to mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

my Issue is regarding with the multiple file uploads. Am using [Viral Patel example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/comment-page-1/#comment-245712) as reference and am able to upload any type of file to db which is storing and retrieving very well. and file is storing in mysql db as blob type. Now my requirement is to upload not one file but to upload multiple files. I had added a button using javascript to add more files. it is working fine. but no columns are creating dynamically if i add 2 or 3 files. please suggest me . below is my code

this is my POJO class:

```
   **POJO CLASS**

   @Entity
   @Table(name="AGREEMENT") 
   public class Agreement implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2641L;


   @Id
     @Column(name="AGREEMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int agreementId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
     private Customer customer;

     @Column(name="CONTENT")
     @Lob
     private Blob content;


     @Column(name="filename")
      private String filename;

     @Column(name="content_type")
     private String contentType;

   //getters and setters
      }
```

This is the controller:

```
   **Controller**
      @RequestMapping(value="/agreement.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public ModelAndView agreementForm(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, 
      Agreement agreement) {
            int customerId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            logger.info("Agreememt to be added" +customerId);
            Customer customer = new Customer(customerId);
            agreement.setCustomer(customer);
            model.addAttribute("agreement", agreement);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("addAgreement");
            return mav;
    }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/addAgreement.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)

     public String queryAddConfirm(@ModelAttribute Agreement  
      agreement,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, BindingResult result, ModelMap 
      model, HttpServletRequest servlet, HttpSession session) throws Exception
    {       

    Long fileSize = file.getSize();

    Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.openSession()).
     createBlob(file.getInputStream(), fileSize);

      logger.info("Added Agreements");
        //query.setContent(content);
        agreement.setContent(blob);
        agreement.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        agreement.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename().toString());



      model.addAttribute("agreement", agreement);
      model.addAttribute("agreement", agreement.getCustomer());

      System.out.println("customerID"+agreement.getCustomer());
      customerService.addAgreements(agreement);

    return "redirect:/customerAdmin/adminListAgreement.htm";
    }
     @RequestMapping("/download/{agreementId}")
        public String download(@PathVariable("agreementId")
                Integer agreementId, HttpServletResponse response) {


           Agreement agreement = customerService.fileDownload(agreementId);
            try {
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" 
                    +agreement.getFilename().toString()+ "\"");


                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType(agreement.getContentType().toString());
                IOUtils.copy(agreement.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);


                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
            }
```

This is Dao Implementation layer:

```
      **Customer DaoIMPL**
          public void addAgreements(Agreement agreement) {

           getCurrentSession().save(agreement); 
                }
```

This is adding the file jsp. in this i have created a button called "add file". when i click the add button a new browse button is creating and am able to select the files. but in the db dynamically rows were not created after submitting. please help me how dynamically columns are added and how can i download(retrieve) it.

```
      **addAgreement JSP**

      <div id=add-container align="center" style="height:400px;width:400px"><br>
                        <p><font color="white" size="6px" face="Comic sans MS" >Add 
        Agreement</font></p><hr>


            <div class="containerdiv" align="center">


                    <form:label path="customer" type="text" align="left" value="" 
             maxlength="50">Customer ID :<span class="error"></span></form:label>
                    <form:input style="width:300px" path="customer" readonly="true"/>
                    <font color="red"><form:errors path="customer" /></font></div><br>


        <p>Select files to upload. Press Add button to add more file inputs.</p> 


    <input id="addFile" type="button" value="Add File" />

      <div class="containerdiv" align="center">
          <table id="fileTable" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="file" id= "file" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>


         </table></div>
        <br>
          <div class="row" Align="center" margin-top: "15px;">
                        <input  class="submit" style="width:150px" type="submit"  
             value="upload" class="large-centered radius button columns"/>


                        <input class="cancel" style="width:150px" type="button" 
         value="Cancel" class="large-centered columns button disabled radius closeButton" 
          onclick=" goBack()"/>
                    </div>    


                </div>
```

controller to show list of added files

```
           **listAgreement GET(controller)**


           @RequestMapping(value="/adminListAgreement.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String AgreementList(ModelMap model) {
            logger.info("Admin List Agreement GET");
            List<Agreement> agreement = customerService.findAllAgreements();
            model.addAttribute("agreement", agreement);
            return "adminListAgreement";
    }
```

This is the list of files adeed jsp

```
         **listAgreement JSP**

    <tr>  

                            <td class="heading">Agreement Id</td>
                            <td class="heading">Content</td>
                            <td class="heading">File Name</td>
                            <td class="heading">CustomerID</td>

                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${agreement}" var="agreement" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>${agreement.agreementId}</td> 
                              <td>
                               <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customerAdmin 
                 /download/${agreement.agreementId}.htm">
                               <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images
              /download1.jpg" 
                               border="0"
                                title="Download this document"/></a> 
                             </td>  
                               <td> ${agreement.filename}</td> 

                               <td>${agreement.customer}</td> 
                            <%--  <td>${query.image}</td> --%>

                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>


      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         //add more file components if Add is clicked
            $('#addFile').click(function() {
       var fileIndex = $('#fileTable tr').children().length - 1;
        $('#fileTable').append(
            '<tr><td>'+
            '   <input type="file" name="files['+ fileIndex +']" />'+
            '</td></tr>'
            );
       });

     });
     </script>
```

Comment: please show the link for `Viral Patel` from where you started this example

Comment: ok . here is the link. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/comment-page-1/#comment-245712

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by just putting different path to download by putting 10 browse button to add ten files but not with the auto add button. i just added ten column and ten browse buttons and kept the different download path to download it.:)